# How to remove the "\n" from the end of my string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I had a list that read from a text file into an array but now they all have "\n" on the end. Obviously you dont see it when you print it because it just takes a new line. I want to remove it because it is causing me some hassle.

```
database = open("database.txt", "r")
databaselist = database.readlines()
```

thats the code i used to read from the file. I am a total noob so please dont use crazy technical talk otherwise it will go straight over my head

Answer (score 2):

```
"string with or without newline\n".rstrip('\n')
```

Using `rstrip` with `\n` avoids any unwanted side-effect except that it will remove multiple \n at the end, if present.

Otherwise, you need to use this less elegant function:

```
def rstrip1(s, c):
    return s[:-1] if s[-1]==c else s
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the correct way of using it in this case. Mentioning some of the side effects: using `strip()` without arguments will also remove any trailing white spaces or tabs `\t`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) to remove the newline character at the end of each line:

```
databaselist = [line.rstrip("\n") for line in database.readlines()]
```

---

However, I recommend that you make three more changes to your code to improve efficiency:

1. Remove the call to `readlines`. Iterating over a file object yields its lines one at a time.
2. Remove the `"r"` argument to `open` since the function defaults to read-mode.  This will not improve the speed of your code, but it will make it less redundant.
3. Most importantly, use a [with-statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) to open the file.  This will ensure that it is closed automatically when you are done.

In all, the new code will look like this:

```
with open("database.txt") as database:
    databaselist = [line.rstrip("\n") for line in database]
```

Comment: `.rstrip('\n')` in case it is a tab-delimited database with a blank field at the end (`\t\n`)